# sed: get a line number with regex and insert text at that line

Tags: sed

I want to get the first line of a file that is not commented out with an hash, then append a line of text <s>just after that line</s> just before that line.

I managed to get the number of the line:

```
sed -n '/^\s*#/!{=;q}' file            // prints 2
```

and also to insert text (specifying the line manually):

```
sed '2 a extralinecontent' file
```

I can't get them working together as a one liner or in a batch.

I tried command substitution (with `$(command)` and also with backticks) but I get an error from bash:

```
sed '$(sed -n '/^\s*#/!{=;q}' file) a extralinecontent' file
-bash: !{=: event not found
```

and also tried many other combinations, but no luck.

I'm using gnu-sed (via brew) on macOS.

Comment: could you post the exact command you tried with `$()`? I'm guessing you used it within double quotes, in which case `!` being special creates the conflict... you could try this instead: `sed $(sed -n '/^\s*#/!{=;q}' file)' a foo' file` where `$()` and rest of the command are next to each other

Comment: I posted it, it's the last code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with `GNU sed` without reading the file twice

```
$ cat ip.txt
 #comment
 foo baz good
123 456 7889

$ sed -e '0,/^\s*[^#[:space:]]/ {// a XYZ' -e '}' ip.txt
 #comment
 foo baz good
XYZ
123 456 7889
```

- `GNU sed` allows first address to be `0` if the other address is regex, that way this will work even if first line matches the condition
- `/^\s*[^#[:space:]]/` as `sed` doesn't support possessive quantifier, need to ensure that the first character being matched by the character class isn't either a `#` or a whitespace character
- `//` is a handy shortcut to repeat the last regex
- `a XYZ` your required line to be appended (note that your question mentiones `insert`, so if you want that, use `i` instead of `a`)

Comment: sed: 1: "0,/^\s*[^#[:space:]]/ { ...": command a expects \ followed by text

Comment: are you using GNU sed? the error you get seems that you are not

Comment: You are right dude, I tested it last night and I forgot to use `gsed` instead of `sed`. Will try this evening. Should I delete all comments?

Comment: you can leave it or clean it up after checking it whether it works for you

Comment: Ok, I tried. No error, but the text is appended to the line after the first without comment. It should be added just after the last with comment.

Comment: Actually, I re-read my question and it's what I wrote, but I was thinking another thing.

Comment: Solved with `i`, instead of `a`, like you stated in the last point.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/^\s*#/b;a extra line content' -e ':a;n;ba' file
```

Bail out of any lines beginning with a comment at the beginning of the file, append an extra line following the first line that is not a comment and keep fetching/printing all the remaining lines of the file.

Comment: Thanks, it works, I modified my question since I need to insert before, not after (I just get confused, I meant after the last commented line).